# Including Folder in Python

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I need to convert .c files into .i files and use that .i file for further processing(in Python). i am using this python code

```
import os
os.system('gcc -E ./foo.c -o ./foo.i')
```

but in my c files contain lot of internal dependencies so it is unable to surf all the dependencies path. How can i include multiple directories and files refereed in c file into my python code so that it converts the file. 
Thanks

Comment: So what you're saying is that you have .c files that could contain paths to other .c files, which could be anywhere, and you want to execute a command on all of them?

Comment: Better to use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) with `shell=True`. That might do it, if the same command on your terminal (manually done) executes successfully.

Comment: @timgeb more exactly my .c file contains  .h files which include other .h file. and i want a pre-processed file, which will have all the content in it.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil - `os.system` does the same thing as `subprocess.call` _Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute._

Comment: Yes, but with the `shell=True`, `subprocess` can leverage your local shell environment, which may be exactly what you want. Plus, `subprocess` is much better in general.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil but then how will the paths be given. if you describe in an example.

Comment: For examples, I suggest taking the conversation to [chat], specially the [python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). If I am not available, someone else can certainly take a look.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil To access [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) you need at least 20 reputations.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. So, the paths should be treated (by `subprocess`) in the same way as those in `os.system`, I am not sure though. In any case, you could always use the complete path, by using any of `os.abspath` or `os.path.join` with `os.getcwd()`, etc.